# controller Syntax with transclude

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to customize directuve 'angular-popover'.

```
<a angular-popover
   direction="bottom"
   template-url="assets/app/common/templates/popovers/page-choose.html"
   class="content_paginator_trigger openPaginator inline-block pull-left">
    <span class="content_paginator_trigger_text popoverTriger">
        Page {{$ctrl.data.current_page}} of {{$ctrl.data.last_page || 1}}
    </span>
</a>
```

That directive use inherit scope.

```
scope: true
```

$ctrl outside, inside and in the 'template-url' is the same.

If I change it on isolate scope then I'm loosing $ctrl context in template. Template is adding via ng-transclude attribute

```
scope: {
    onOpen: "&onOpen"
}
```

How can I pass some function from $ctrl to 'angularPopover' directive?

Comment: I'm saving the $ctrl context in this way:
scope: {
    $ctrl: '=context'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service that gets called by both the controller and the directive.

```js
(function (ng) {
  'use strict';

  ng.module('ServiceDemo')
    .service('DemoService', DemoService)
    .controller('DemoController', DemoController)
    .directive('DemoDirective', DemoDirective);

  function DemoService () {
    var self = this;

    self.onOpen = onOpen;

    function onOpen () {
      console.log('onOpen called!');
    }
  }

  function DemoController (DemoService) {
    var demoControllerVM = this;

    demoControllerVM.onOpen = DemoService.onOpen;
  }

  function DemoDirective (DemoService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'path/to/directive/template.html',
      controllerAs: 'demoDirectiveVM',
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var demoDirectiveVM = this;

        demoDirectiveVM.onOpen = DemoService.onOpen;
      }
    };
  }
})(angular);
```

Comment: Not the best solution for controller of component, but I can use it. Thanks.